# Are terminal singularities $ \mathbb{Q}$-factorial?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program

The proof of Lemma 5-1-5 in this 1987 paper by Kawamata, Matsuda and  Matsuki [(link on Projecteuclid)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aspm/1525310275)  seems to say that a variety with terminal singularities is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial ( I only need the case $ \Delta =0$ in which case, weak log terminal might be the same as just terminal.). Does anyone know how to prove this, or a place where this is proved?

Comment: In dimension two all klt singularities are $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial. In dimension three there are singularities which are terminal and not $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial, for instance the cone over $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$. The Lemma you cite only talks about fibrations, I don't know how it would imply such statement.

In any case, if you have a klt singularity, you can make it $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial with a small morphism, this is called a small $\mathbb{Q}$-factorialization.

Comment: I believe the paper assumes at the very beginning of section 5-1 that $X$ is $\mathbb Q$-factorial? As @JoaquínMoraga says, this is not true otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how you get this conclusion from the paper of Kawamata, Matsuda and Matsuki. But this is not true in dimension at least $3$. Of course in dimension 2 every terminal singularity is smooth.

The easiest example of a non-$\mathbb{Q}$-factorial terminal singularity in dimension $3$ is the hypersurface $(xy=zw)\subset \mathbb{A}^4_{x,y,z,w}$. It is terminal as it admits a crepant small resolution. On the other hand, it is not $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial, as there are $2$ Weil divisors $D=(x=z=0)$ and $D'=(y=w=0)$ such that the intersection $D\cap D'$ is exactly one point, the origin. This contradicts the fact that the intersection of $2$ $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor has codimension at least $2$.